# jsTree causes that links on whole page are broken

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jstree

Greetings, 
I have the following problem. In my asp.net mvc page (which is a partial view) I create an instance of jsTree as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#industries").tree({
            callback: {
                onselect: function(NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
                    $("#SelectedIndustryROWGUID").val($(NODE).attr("id"));
                    $("#resultMessage").append($(NODE).attr("rel"));
                }
            },
            data: {
                type: "json",
                async: true,
                opts: {
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "/CreateMessage/GetIndustries/"
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

this works fine but then, when I click on any link on the page, it does not work. The links are executed when I choose "open in new tab" option from context menu. When I remove the above part, everything is working fine
Can someone please help me with this?

**EDIT**
I've changed the code above to be as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#industries").tree({
        callback: {
            onselect: function(NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
                $("#SelectedIndustryROWGUID").val($(NODE).attr("id"));
                $("#resultMessage").append($(NODE).attr("rel"));
            }
        },
        data: {
            type: "json",
            async: true,
            opts: {
                method: "POST",
                url: "/CreateMessage/GetIndustries/"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

(I've added $(document).ready(function() { ...
but it also didn't helped

**EDIT2**
I also asked this question on jsTree discussion group and I received an answer. Upgrading jquery to version 1.4.2 solved the problem!

Comment: If this question is solved, please select an answer and mark it answered. If the answers aren't correct, you can add your own answer with the actual solution and then mark it as the answer. Doing this will help people looking for unanswered questions to not waste our time.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, the jquery 1.4.2 update worked wonders for me too.  First time I've seen a bug in jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { <--- here change to --> $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#industries").tree({
```

when you do `$(something)`, jquery expects the "something" to be a selector, in your code your directly giving it a function instead of anything jquery considers to be a selector.

Comment: I;ve edited my original question. I've added the code you suggessted but it also didn't help

Comment: I've added alert("test"+$(NODE).attr("id")); for this jsTree. I;ve noticed that this alert is also executed when I click on links within the page